# How to get defined display names (id) from selected view?

Tags: 7, views

Getting selected view is simple:

> views_get_view('name');

I didn't find and have no idea what do next...

I need to get every defined view page path and add menu item to it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will loop through every page display and set a menu item.

```
  $view = views_get_view('VIEW_NAME');
  foreach ($view->display as &$display) {
    if ($display->display_plugin == 'page') {
      // Add an if or switch statement here to check $display->id
      // so you can set different menu items for each display.
      $display->display_options['menu'] = array(
        'type' => 'normal', // Menu item type.
        'title' => t('Menu item title'), // Menu item title
        'description' => '', // Menu item description
        'name' => 'main-menu', // Menu name
        'weight' => 0, // Menu item weight
        'context' => 0, // Not sure off the top of my head what this is for.
      );
    }
  }
```

However this will set the same menu item for each display.
You will need to check the $display->id for each one so that you can set a different menu item for each display.

Also, that example sets a normal menu item.
If you want a local task or default local task it will be slightly different.

...also, why do you need to do this? why not add the menu item via the views UI?

Comment: "...also, why do you need to do this? why not add the menu item via the views UI?" Long story, I am migrating from Joomla. In this menu (besides links from Views) I need to add other links (dynamic - GET params). Migration must be repeatable too. I want to have it all in one place.